# No signature of method: script.findFiles() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap)

Tags: jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

Am running the following code in a groovy script inside Jenkins job DSl.

```
    List<String> jenkinsfilePaths = findFiles(glob: '**/*/Jenkinsfile').collect { it.path }

    // Provision folder and Multibranch Pipelines.
    jobDsl(
            scriptText: libraryResource('multiPipelines.groovy'),
            additionalParameters: [
                    jenkinsfilePathsStr: jenkinsfilePaths,
                    rootFolderStr      : rootFolderPath,
                    repositoryURL      : env.GIT_URL
            ],
            // The following may be set to 'DELETE'. Note that branches will compete to delete and recreate items
            // unless you only provision items from the default branch.
            removedJobAction: 'IGNORE'
    )
```

I am getting the following error despite having installed the plugin.

`No signature of method: script.findFiles() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[glob:**/*/Jenkinsfile]]`